# Como cargar correctamente Jquery y Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Buenos dias a todos, estoy haciendo una web que hace uso de JQuery y de Bootstrap (incluido algunos plugins como DateTimePicker). Mas o menos consigo hacerlo funcionar pero no consigo que me quede claro el tema de las cargas de los distintos scripts y estilos. Por ejemplo, yo tengo la siguiente pagina de inicio, un formulario que valida si existe un usuario:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='js_propio/cookies.js'></script>
  <script src='js_propio/funciones.js'></script>
  <script src='js_propio/eventos.js'></script>


  <!-- -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/vendor.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/flat-admin.css">

  <!-- Theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/theme/blue-sky.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/theme/blue.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/theme/red.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/theme/yellow.css">  
</head>
<body>

<!-- AQUI VA EL CONTENIDO -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/vendor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
  <script src='js_propio/cookies.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Por las funciones que yo tengo programada, realizo las cargas de las otras paginas con un metodo GET, que limpia un determinado DIV y carga dentro el html.

Aqui un ejemplo de la funcion:

```
 $('body').on('click', "#btnCita", function(ev){
      $.get( "form.html", function( data ) {
           $("#carga").html('');
           $("#carga").html(data);
           selecEspecialidad();
    });           
  });
```

El problema que surge es que, si dejo las llamadas a scripts que hay en su head(las mismas que las que hay en el head de la pagina principal) muchas veces las funciones se me ejecutan dos veces, en cambio, si las elimino y dejo html solamente, intentando que haga uso de los scripts que hay en la pagina principal, no se ejecutan.

Asimismo, en otra de las cargas, llamo a una pagina con un formulario, en el que uno de los campos es un calendario (en español).

> El problema aqui reside en que, la configuracion del calendario se
>   encuentra dentro de un  $(document).ready(function()), por lo que no
>   se ejecuta correctamente al ejecutarse al cargar la pagina, y no al
>   ser cargada en la pagina principal (no se si me he explicado bien)

(EDICIÓN : éste ultimo párrafo no lo puedo editar para mejorar la redacción porque no se entiende la idea).

```
     <div class="row" id="datosCita">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header oculto">
              Rellene los siguientes datos
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row"> 
                <div  id="datos" class="oculto">
                  <select class="select2" id="listEspec">
                    <option value="0">-- Seleccione una especialidad --</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div id="profesionales" class="oculto">
                  <select class="select2" id="listProf">
                    <option value="0">-- Seleccione un profesional --</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group oculto">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </div>
                  <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type="text"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="cargaTablaCitas"></div>     
              <div id="iconosNav">
                <img src="iconos/siguiente.png" id="btnSiguiente" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-footer">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar cita</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/vendor.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
       <script src='js_propio/cookies.js'></script>

    <!-- Include Date Range Picker -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

        var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
        var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
        date_input.datepicker({
        useCurrent: false,
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: "today",
        language: 'es'
        }).on('closeUp',function(){
          var marca = true;
          if(marca == true){
             alert($(this).val());

          }
          //alert('a');

        })
      })
    </script>

    <script src='js_propio/eventos.js'></script>
```

Como he dicho anteriormente, consigo hacerlo funcionar pero cambiando de orden los script a lo loco.

Comment: No entiendo mucho la pregunta ni cual es el problema, creo que no está muy claro que es lo que te pasa realmente. Y tampoco entiendo por qué cargas 2 datepicker js en los scripts, quizás eso es lo que te está causando el problema. Revisa bien el orden en que cargas tus scripts y que no repitas ninguno

Answer (score 4):

el orden lo explica Minerillo muy bien, yo opto por lo siguiente aunque ya no tiene mucha valides en mi trabajo (después explico porque):

### Hojas de Estilo CSS

en el `<head>`

`<head>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/cssOtrasLibrerias.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/cssCreadorPorMi.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>`

Recuerda que las CSS se sobre escriben y siempre se toma la ultima, en caso de ser una definición identica, por eso siempre se empieza por el `Framework`, despues las `librerias`(como alertas, modales, temas, etc..) y por último las personalizadas.

### Métodos y Scripts JS

antes de cerrar el `<body>`

```
   <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <script src="js/pluginX.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libreriaY.js"></script>
   <script src="js/misMetodos.js"></script>
   <script>console.log('otros metodos');</script>
</body>
```

El orden aquí si influye, pues `bootstrap` necesita de `jquery`, asi que necesita que este cargado, y puede que un plugin necesite de otro como el `datepicker`y el `datetimepicker`que son dependientes.

Todo en orden y muy bien arreglado.

## Preguntas Comunes:

#### ¿Por que me ejecuta la función 2 veces?

Por que si cargas un archivo con .load(), vuelve a cargar una página con todos sus scripts, es normal que se ejecute 2 o más veces.

#### ¿Como puedo cargar contenido de otra página sin que esto pase?

Bueno, ya cargaste los CSS y los JS, así que en teoria tus páginas que vas a cargar solo deberian tener el HTML, ya que si no estarías duplicando código.

#### Pero si cargo solo el HTML ¿Por que mi JS no funciona?

Como dijo @Minerillo, es un problema de querer asignar algo, a otra cosa que aun no existe. y para eso lo siguiente:

supongamos que tienes un código **HTML**, asi

```
<div class="contenido">
   <button id="llamar">Llamar Algo</button>
</div>
```

y que en la primera página tienes un **método JS** (o función);

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#llamar').on('click', function(){ alert('llamando')});
});
```

Ya que el documento esta listo al dar click en el boton ejecuta la llamada, todo chulo hasta aquí.

---

Ahora tienes otro HTML (boton.html)

```
<button id="nada">Alertar Nada</button>
```

lo cargas con `.load()` al div que mencionamos antes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#llamar').on('click', function(){
       $('.contenido').load('boton.html');
   });
});
```

Y quieres que ahora ese **nuevo boton** haga algo y lo pones ahi también:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#llamar').on('click', function(){
       $('.contenido').load('boton.html')
   });

  $('#nada').on('click', function(){
       alert('Presionaste Nada');
  });
});
```

pero ... no funciona :(

#### ¿Por que no funciona el nuevo boton?

Veras, el contenido se carga la primera vez, eso activa el `$(document).ready()' cuando tu cargas otro HTML que no existia en el momento que`$(document).ready()' pasó, pues no hay como decir que reaccione a tu evento `.on('click')` por eso no hace nada.

¿Como te mandaria tu mamá a las tortillas si aun no naces? (Un ejemplo en la vida real)

#### ¿Como solucionarlo?

Veras. supongamos que tu no puedes ordenar algo a algo que no existe, sin embargo sabes donde y cuando va a existir.

Bueno la explicación larga aqui: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Para asignar un evento a algo que sabemos que va a existir, debemos agregarlo a quien lo contiene, en este caso nuestro `<div class="contenido">`

Entonces:

```
<!--                           |-- Este hace la magia               -->
<!--                           |                                   -->
$('.contenido').on('click', '#nada', function(){
    alert('Presionaste Nada');
});
```

Funcionaria por que le estas asignando un evento a algo que ya existe. Y este a su vez va a a conocer que elemento activa el evento.

Nuestro código final queda así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#llamar').on('click', function(){
       $('.contenido').load('boton.html')
   });

  $('.contenido').on('click', '#nada', function(){
       alert('Presionaste Nada');
  });
});
```

#### ¿Por que decias que ya no se usa la forma de ordenar?

Hoy en día está de moda los precompiladores, transpiladores y empaquetadores. Los cuales juntan todo el código, lo machacan y lo comprimen quedando un sitio que consta de 2 archivos.

Disminuyendo peticiones, aunque sacrificando otras cosas. Entonces al final esa serie de herramientas acomodan todo. Aunque claro no es mágico y se debe tener dominados estos temas para saber que estas haciendo.

Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

La razón principal por la que Bootstrap falla es cuando no tiene Jquery previamente.

En la documentación de Bootstrap comentan la necesidad de que JQuery, este ANTES que Bootstrap JS.

*Primero de todo
`<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-X.X.X.min.js"></script>`
Puedes encontrar la ultima versión jquery en:
http://jquery.com/download/ 
*Y despues la de bootstrap 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Y de seguido el resto de librerias que necesitas y quieras, pero te recomiendo poner estas dos las primeras dentro del script JS.

Answer (score 1):

Buenos días.

Las dependencias en Javascript ES5 se satisfacen en cascada, de forma que primero se incluye en el archivo HTML aquellos ficheros javascript que no dependen de ningún otro fichero, y por último, se añade el que necesita de los anteriores.

En tu caso, como estamos usando Bootstrap 3 sería:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pathTojQuery.min.js"></script>
```

y luego

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pathToBootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

De esta forma, cuando el archivo bootstrap.min.js busque la dependencia de jQuery necesaria para éste, ya está cargada debido a que se declaró anteriormente y consecuentemente, se cargará antes que bootstrap.

En el caso de Boostrap 4, que aun está en versión alpha, primero tendrías que cargar jQuery, luego tether (otra dependencia de bootstrap 4), y por último bootstrap. De esa forma evitamos que la consola de errores del navegador nos chille con los molestos errores.

Un saludo

Comment: Para referirse a un script externo, se declaran en la propiedad **src**: `<script type="text/javascript" src="pathTojQuery.min.js">`

Comment: Es cierto, me di cuenta cuando puse la respuesta que no lo había puesto correctamente.

Comment: Siempre estás a tiempo de editarla.