# Varios errores de archivos vinculados en header y footer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Recientemente he actualizado mi web, que estoy probando en localhost, y he tenido que añadir y modificar tanto la cabecera como el pie de página.
Creo que he debido cambiar sin querer algunos vínculos de bootstrap y jquery, porque en la consola del navegador me aparecen estos dos errores:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: DataTable is not defined
> at admin.php:445:5
>
> functions.js:68 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a
> function
> at HTMLDocument. (functions.js:68:22)
> at j (jquery.min.js:2:27295)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:28108)
> at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2:29942)
> at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2:30308)

En el head tengo esto:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.3/css/dataTables.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/css/main.css"/>
```

Y antes de cerrar el body esto:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.3/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/js/functions.js"></script>
```

Ya no se que he cambiado ni movido de arriba a abajo intentando arreglarlo, así que perdonen si hay cosas repetidas o eliminadas.
 En otra conversación de Stackoverflow en español leí que debe ir delante jquery, pero si utilizas Datatables este debe ir antes de bootstrap.

Comment: 1. Primero debés importar jQuery, luego Bootstrap (la versión de BS que estás utilizando depende de jQuery). 2. Tenés versiones distintas de jQuery allí, e importaciones de CSS y JS duplicadas. 3. Probablemente quisiste importar los JS antes de cerrar el body, no en el footer.

Comment: la de Jquery es la 3.7.1 y ahora utilizo la 3.3.4 de Bootstrap. El problema es que si cambio la de Bootstrap el diseño de mi web cambia y ya no se parece a nada.

Comment: Vi en esta página que colocaban en el head los css y justo antes del cierre del body los js, colocando jquery y datatables lo primero: <br/> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68840/como-cargar-correctamente-jquery-y-bootstrap. Y así lo he hecho, pero me siguen apareciendo estos dos errores:  admin.php:445 Uncaught ReferenceError: DataTable is not defined
    at admin.php:445:5
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (functions.js:68:22)

Comment: Si hiciste el cambio, reflejalo en la pregunta a través de una edición. Tené en cuenta además qué versiones de cada librería estás utilizando.

Comment: Ya lo he arreglado. He añadido las librerías de datepicker de css y js. Además, el script de jquery debe ir en el head y las dos librerías de Datatables tienen que ir juntas arriba también. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pero si tenías scripts de jQuery duplicados...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero que nada debes aprender a ubicar los archivos. la norma de la comunidad de desarrolladores web dice que:

- En el `Head` debe ir los CSS.
- En el `Body` al final los JS.

**Ejemplo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sabiando ya donde va cada cosa, este debe ser el orden tanto para CSS y JS, este orden esta relacionado a la carga de pre-requisitos:

1. Libreria de Jquery (JS/CSS).
2. Libreria de Diseño (Bootstrap/Tailwin/Etc JS/CSS).
3. Libreria de Plugins (JS/CSS)
4. Libreria de Plugins Configuraciones adicionales (JS/CSS)
5. Libreria Personales o de implementacion de todo lo anterior (JS/CSS)

**Porque?**

Muchos aseguran que el poner el CSS **solo** en el header provocara que los estilos que se requieran esten disponibles en el momento de renderizado del html (no lo he probado, ni cuestionado), esto permite que el pintado de los elemento no sea bloqueado por la ejecucion de codigo javascript, motivo que nos lleva al siguiente parrafo.

Muchos aseguran que el poner el javascript en el body **previene que se bloque** el pintado/renderizado del codigo html, simplemente el html se pintara, aunque el javascript no este disponible.

Hasta este punto a mi me ha funcionado todo correctamente... en cuanto al orden especifico 1,2,3,4,5 es el orden en que deben ser cargados los pre-requisitos.

Tambien es importante no duplicar librerias de diferentes versiones. siempre tienes que migrar a la ultima version.

**Errores detectados**

*Este orden es incorrecto:*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="...dataTables.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="...3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Aqui primero debe ir el BS... ya que datatable implementa algunos estilos de BS...

*duplicado de script:*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="...jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="...dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="...1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

haca como veras tienes dos veces jquery de dos CDN y versiones diferentes...