no me hace el calculo con javascript
estoy desarrollando un simulador de cálculo energetico en viviendas con aerotermia. Para este proyecto tengo un archivo html, un archivo js, uno php y un json. Cuando meto los datos en el formulario y se ejecuta el cáculo, los datos no salen en la interfaz web del usuario y no se insertan en las tablas de la base de datos. Os pongo el archivo php y el archivo js
simulator.php
/ Crear conexión
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Verificar la conexión
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error));
    exit();
}

// Verificar si se han enviado datos por POST
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Obtener los datos del formulario
    $provincia = $_POST["provincia"];
    $area = $_POST["area"];
    $temp_ext = $_POST["temp_ext"];
    $personas = $_POST["personas"];
    $habitaciones = $_POST["habitaciones"];

    // Cargar el archivo JSON con los datos de demanda energética por provincia
    $datos_provincias = json_decode(file_get_contents('datos_provincias.json'), true);

    // Verificar si la provincia seleccionada está en el archivo JSON
    if (array_key_exists($provincia, $datos_provincias)) {
        // Obtener los valores de demanda energética para la provincia seleccionada
        $demanda_calefaccion_convencional = $datos_provincias[$provincia]["demanda_calefaccion_convencional"];
        $demanda_refrigeracion_convencional = $datos_provincias[$provincia]["demanda_refrigeracion_convencional"];
        $demanda_calefaccion_aerotermia = $datos_provincias[$provincia]["demanda_calefaccion_aerotermia"];
        $demanda_refrigeracion_aerotermia = $datos_provincias[$provincia]["demanda_refrigeracion_aerotermia"];

        // Realizar el cálculo (simulación simple)
        $demanda_calefaccion = $area * $temp_ext * $personas;
        $demanda_refrigeracion = $area * $temp_ext * $personas / 2;
        $costo_energetico = ($area * $temp_ext * $personas) * 0.1; // Precio ficticio por kWh

        // Calcular el ahorro energético
        $ahorro_energetico_calefaccion = $demanda_calefaccion_convencional - $demanda_calefaccion_aerotermia;
        $ahorro_energetico_refrigeracion = $demanda_refrigeracion_convencional - $demanda_refrigeracion_aerotermia;
        $ahorro_energetico_total = $ahorro_energetico_calefaccion + $ahorro_energetico_refrigeracion;

        // Insertar los datos en la tabla 'datos_vivienda'
        $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO datos_vivienda (`provincia`, area, temperatura_exterior, personas, habitaciones) VALUES ('$provincia', $area, $temp_ext, $personas, $habitaciones)";
        if ($conn->query($sql_insert) === TRUE) {
            $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
            // Insertar los resultados en la tabla 'resultados_simulacion' junto con el ID de la vivienda
            $sql_insert_resultados = "INSERT INTO resultados_simulacion (id_datos_vivienda, demanda_calefaccion, demanda_refrigeracion, costo_energetico, ahorro_energetico_calefaccion, ahorro_energetico_refrigeracion, ahorro_energetico_total) VALUES ($last_id, $demanda_calefaccion, $demanda_refrigeracion, $costo_energetico, $ahorro_energetico_calefaccion, $ahorro_energetico_refrigeracion, $ahorro_energetico_total)";
            if ($conn->query($sql_insert_resultados) === TRUE) {
                // Devolver el resultado como JSON
                echo json_encode(array(
                    "demanda_calefaccion" => $demanda_calefaccion,
                    "demanda_refrigeracion" => $demanda_refrigeracion,
                    "costo_energetico" => $costo_energetico,
                    "ahorro_energetico_calefaccion" => $ahorro_energetico_calefaccion,
                    "ahorro_energetico_refrigeracion" => $ahorro_energetico_refrigeracion,
                    "ahorro_energetico_total" => $ahorro_energetico_total,
                    "provincia" => $provincia,
                    "area" => $area,
                    "temp_ext" => $temp_ext,
                    "personas" => $personas,
                    "habitaciones" => $habitaciones
                ));
            } else {
                // Si falla la inserción en 'resultados_simulacion', devolver un error
                http_response_code(500);
                echo json_encode(array("error" => "Error al insertar los resultados en la tabla 'resultados_simulacion'"));
            }
        } else {
            // Si falla la inserción en 'datos_vivienda', devolver un error
            http_response_code(500);
            echo json_encode(array("error" => "Error al insertar los datos en la tabla 'datos_vivienda'"));
        }
    } else {
        // Si la provincia seleccionada no está en el archivo JSON, devolver un error
        http_response_code(400);
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "No se encontraron datos para la provincia seleccionada"));
    }
} else {
    // Si no se envían datos por POST, devolver un error
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "No se han recibido datos"));
}
?>

Y este es el archivo script.js
    fetch('simulator.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log("Respuesta del servidor:", data);
    
    // Mostrar los resultados en la página
    document.getElementById('demanda_calefaccion').innerText = 'Demanda de calefacción: ' + data.demanda_calefaccion + ' kWh';
    document.getElementById('demanda_refrigeracion').innerText = 'Demanda de refrigeración: ' + data.demanda_refrigeracion + ' kWh';
    document.getElementById('costo_energetico').innerText = 'Costo energético: $' + data.costo_energetico;

    // Mostrar el ahorro energético
    document.getElementById('ahorro_calefaccion').innerText = 'Ahorro de calefacción: ' + data.ahorro_energetico_calefaccion + ' kWh';
    document.getElementById('ahorro_refrigeracion').innerText = 'Ahorro de refrigeración: ' + data.ahorro_energetico_refrigeracion + ' kWh';
    document.getElementById('ahorro_total').innerText = 'Ahorro energético total: ' + data.ahorro_energetico_total + ' kWh';

    // Crear la gráfica
    var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Calefacción', 'Refrigeración'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Demanda Energética (kWh)',
                data: [data.demanda_calefaccion, data.demanda_refrigeracion],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Mostrar el contenedor de resultados
    document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'block';

    // Agregar evento de clic al botón de descarga de PDF
    document.getElementById('downloadPDF').addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Crear el PDF
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var canvas = document.getElementById('chart');
        var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        // Agregar el título y los datos al PDF
        doc.text('Resultados del simulador de aerotermia', 10, 10);
        doc.text('Demanda de calefacción: ' + data.demanda_calefaccion + ' kWh', 10, 30);
        doc.text('Demanda de refrigeración: ' + data.demanda_refrigeracion + ' kWh', 10, 40);
        doc.text('Costo energético: $' + data.costo_energetico, 10, 50);
        doc.text('Ahorro de calefacción: ' + data.ahorro_energetico_calefaccion + ' kWh', 10, 60);
        doc.text('Ahorro de refrigeración: ' + data.ahorro_energetico_refrigeracion + ' kWh', 10, 70);
        doc.text('Ahorro energético total: ' + data.ahorro_energetico_total + ' kWh', 10, 80);
        
        // Agregar la imagen de la gráfica al PDF
        doc.addImage(imageData, 'PNG', 10, 90, 180, 100);

        // Descargar el PDF
        doc.save('resultados_aerotermia.pdf');
    });
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});

cuando miro el error lo único que me devulve es esto - {"demanda_calefaccion":3200,"demanda_refrigeracion":1600,"costo_energetico":320,"ahorro_energetico_calefaccion":-150,"ahorro_energetico_refrigeracion":-100,"ahorro_energetico_total":-250,"provincia":"Toledo","area":"80","temp_ext":"20","personas":"2","habitaciones":"1"} - que son los datos del fomulario, pero no se insertan y el cáculo no me lo muestra en web.
Espero que podáis ayudarme, porque ya no sé qué más hacer. La conexión a la base de datos  es correcta.
Este es el código html que muestra los datos
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simulador de Aerotermia en Viviendas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Simulador de Aerotermia en Viviendas</h1>
         <form id="simulatorForm" action="simulator.php" method="post">
             <label for="provincia">Provincia:</label>
             <select id="provincia" name="provincia" required>
                <option value="">Selecciona una provincia</option>
                <option value="Álava">Álava</option>
                <option value="Albacete">Albacete</option>
                <option value="Madrid">Madrid</option>
                <option value="Toledo">Toledo</option>
                <option value="Sevilla">Sevilla</option>
                <option value="Cádiz">Cádiz</option>
                <option value="Valladolid">Valladolid</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <label for="area">Área de la vivienda (m²):</label>
            <input type="number" id="area" name="area" required><br><br>
            
            <label for="temp_ext">Temperatura exterior (°C):</label>
            <input type="number" id="temp_ext" name="temp_ext" required><br><br>
            
            <label for="personas">Número de habitantes:</label>
            <input type="number" id="personas" name="personas" required><br><br>
            
            <label for="habitaciones">Número de habitaciones:</label>
            <input type="number" id="habitaciones" name="habitaciones" required><br><br>
            
            <button type="submit">Calcular</button>
        </form>
        
        <div id="results" style="display:none;">
            <h2>Resultados</h2>
            <p id="demanda_calefaccion"></p>
            <p id="demanda_refrigeracion"></p>
            <p id="costo_energetico"></p>
            <p id="ahorro_calefaccion"></p> <!-- Nuevo elemento para mostrar el ahorro en calefacción -->
            <p id="ahorro_refrigeracion"></p> <!-- Nuevo elemento para mostrar el ahorro en refrigeración -->
            <p id="ahorro_total"></p> <!-- Nuevo elemento para mostrar el ahorro total -->
            <canvas id="chart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
            <button id="downloadPDF">Descargar PDF</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


No entiendo de que error hablas, ni de que calculas hablas... no veo ninguna de las dos cosas...

Estás viendo justamente lo que estás mostrando desde el servidor: echo json_encode(array("demanda_calefaccion" => $demanda_calefaccion, ... etc... Si quieres ver otra cosa, debes mostrar lo que quieres ver. Dicho eso, ¿cuál es el motivo para escribir nombres de variables kilométricos en tu código? Escribir un programa no es lo mismo que escribir una novela. Considera usar nombres de variable menos largos y que permitan identificar lo que hacen dichas variables. Para ello podría ser de ayuda una convención de nombre en inglés.

me da error de inserción, pero no sé por qué no inserta los datos en la tabla

http_response_code(500);
echo json_encode(array("error" => "Error al insertar los datos en la tabla 'datos_vivienda': " . $conn->error));

lo que falla es la inserción de los datos del campo habitaciones. He repasado todo el código y el nombre está igual y repasado el código SQL de inserción y también lo veo bien, no sé qué es lo que falla. No muestra los datos en la página ni los sube a la tabla porque falla la inserción del campo habitaciones

falta algo que no has programado o salta algun Error fatal / Warning de PHP + Base de datos???

nigún error fatal. Nada que yo pueda ver, hace los cáculos y demás pero no los inserta en las tablas , ni los muestra en web

Ya me carga los datos y los cálculos en las tablas de la base de datos.

Y el problema fue que...?

el problema está en que a pesar de hacer bien los cálculos e insertar los datos en las tablas, los datos se muestran en consola y no com debería de verlo el usuario incluida la gráfica. Lo que se ve es esto:{"demanda_calefaccion":1200,"demanda_refrigeracion":600,"costo_energetico":120,"ahorro_energetico_calefaccion":-150,"ahorro_energetico_refrigeracion":-100,"ahorro_energetico_total":-250,"provincia":"Cadiz","area":"60","temp_ext":"20","personas":"1","habitaciones":"1"}. Puede que el problema esté en JSON, pero no veo cúal puede ser

Ahora ya muestra los datos como los vería el usuario.  El problema estaba en cómo estaba actualizando el DOM con esos datos. Me he asegurado de que el JavaScript se estaba ejecutando después de que el DOM se hubiese cargado completamente. Y me faltaba este código document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
document.getElementById('simulatorForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
event.preventDefault(); // Evitar que el formulario se envíe normalmente
    var formData = new FormData(this); - Ahora ya funciona correctamente.


en la curva de aprendizaje de javascript primero se ve como cuando se hacen las manipulacion de del DOM antes de entrar en eventos y ajax... te has saltado una leccion importante ... hace poco di esta respuesta... que esta relacionada cuando ves html y el orden en el que se insertan los archivo css y js: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/617079/315134

cito esa respuesta por que tiene que entender como se carga el html, el DOM y como interactua la carga de archivos externos CSS y JS...

DOMContentLoaded, dentro de este evento es importante que coloques todos los eventos y metodos que dependan de que el HTML, el DOM y en general la pagina haya cargado.

no pudimos replicar el error por que en tu ejemplo no incluyes todo el codigo y no se sabia que hacia falta o que era o no funcional

Muchas gracias por todos tus comentarios. De esta forma es más fácil aprender.
